# XMLRPC for Windows in C++/C

Tags: c++, c, xml, xml-rpc, rpc

Please help me to find good(at least correct working) XMLRPC library for Windows in C++/C.
I tried XmlRpcC4Win1.0.11 but looks like it have a problem, instead of return just a plain int as a result it returns some complex structure every time.
Please help me to find good library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [ulxmlrpc](http://ulxmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/)